# Menu Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I would like to know how to make the menu appear after user login in magento 2.4?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- If you want the to customer will see the main menu after successfully logged in then you have to check the customer session before load the navigation section.

```
<?php
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
  if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $this->getChildHtml("navigation.sections");
  }
?>
```